# What is the difference between pipx and using pip install inside a virtual environment?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, virtualenv, pipx

I recently used pipx to install a package (That was the recommended install approach for the package). I installed using pip in a virtual environment. I was with the assumption that pipx is in that environment, and then pipx would install the package in the same environment. However, pipx created a environment folder and installed the package there. I had to add the PATH into in order to use that package. This led me to think what the difference between pipx and using pip install inside a virtual environment

Isn't using pip from the virtual environment more convenient to install the package ?

Comment: **Did you try** using both? Do you observe differences?

Comment: https://pipx.pypa.io/stable/#how-is-it-different-from-pip With `pipx` you don't need to add every virtual env to `$PATH`, you only need to add `$HOME/.local/bin` once (but you're recommended to add this anyway for other needs like `pip install --user`).

Comment: @phd Yes that is what I was thinking as I well. I was just curious whether there is a solid difference between the both.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Yes I did try. I used pipx to install poetry also used pip to install it as well. I don't observe any viable difference. That is why I asked the question regarding pipx, hoping it would tell me if there are differences under the hood or those that are not surface level

Comment: @phd From the link you have mentioned, it says "pipx creates an isolated environment for each application and its associated packages". Hence I asked why not just create an virtual environment and then use pip to install packages in that environment ?

Comment: @adiaux "*I asked why not just create an virtual environment and then use pip to install packages…*" `pipx` creates a virtual env, installs the application and its dependecies and links the application into `$HOME/.local/bin`, all automatically, with just one command `pipx install <app>`. With `pip` you need to do everything manually and add it to `$PATH` yourself.